# Primary key choice - multivalued attribute

Tags: sql, relational-database, primary-key

I'm trying to decide on primary key choice for a multivalued attribute and have a quick question:

Given:

```
Customer (cid, name, address, town, post code, email)
Customer_Number(cid, phone_number)
```

where cid is the primary key for the customer, could I define the primary key for the Customer_Number relation as 'phone_number' seeing as this is the minimum attribute which uniquely identifies each record.  I'm assuming that no two customers can have the same phone number.

I'm not sure about this as I feel the cid should be included too.

Would appreciate any advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I'm assuming that no two customers can have the same phone number.

Even if this is correct (which may not be the case if your customers give the same number e.g. same household, same company department), it does not preclude users from entering it incorrectly.

The "surrogate" vs. "non-surrogate" key discussion can be a long and heated one, but a good rule of thumb is not to use a column which is assigned or entered by an end-user, as human errors then come into play. Personally, I'm a big fan of surrogate keys and almost always use them, but your needs may dictate otherwise.

And your actual question has less to do with surrogate-ness or otherwise, and more to do with FK relationships anyway, so treat this as just a side note.

Comment: This reasoning is just so wrong even assuming there are reasons to add a surrogate key (which there may well be). Either it is a business rule that customers must have unique phone numbers or it isn't. If it *IS* a rule that phone numbers must be unique then the key certainly should be (phone_number). That *would* preclude users from entering it incorrecty. The reason why you should enforce keys on columns entered by users is (at least partly) to *prevent* human errors. Yet your argument for not enforcing data integrity constraints of that kind is that you want to *allow* keying errors!

Comment: @sqlvogel: you misunderstand me - I am not suggesting that relaxing referential integrity is ever good, I am simply saying (perhaps unclearly) that sometimes this can be enforced - e.g. with a unique index - without making that column the *primary* key. If the user enters a unique phone number, and it is *wrong*, then it is sometimes much easier to correct it when you are not implicitly re-defining relationships..

Comment: Therefore the choice of "primary" key is actually irrelevant and what matters is that the key on either (phone_number) or (cid, phone_number) is enforced. And it matters just as much (perhaps even more so) if you add a surrogate to the table, which incidentally is something the question gives no idendication is necessary anyway. The suggestion about using a surrogate key doesn't address the question at hand in any useful way.

Comment: Hence my comment to treat it as a side note.

Answer (score 0):

CustomerID has to remain as your foreign key in Customer_Number table. I guess you could create a new column in that table called Customer_Number_ID, since the phone number is not necessarily unique identifier. With that said, you may have 1 customer with multiple telephone numbers, therefore you may need the addition of that column so you can use the combination of both(Customer_number_id and CustomerID) as a composite key when it is required.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like cnid column as PK to Customer_number table and use cid as FK.